# Org clock quarterly report doesn't work anymore

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

In order to summarise my work for certain projects I use Org's clock tables:

```
 #+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope agenda-with-archives :block 2015-Q1 :tags "ProjectA"  :fileskip0
 #+END:
```

This summarises the time spent in the first quarter of 2015. However, today I tried to do this for Q3 and it seems to (partially) fail. as you can see below it Org lists the entries of Q4:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope agenda-with-archives :block 2015-Q3 :tags "ProjectA"  :fileskip0
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2015-10-13 di 10:51], for 4th quarter of 2015.
| File               | Headline             |   Time |      |
|--------------------+----------------------+--------+------|
|                    | ALL *Total time*     | *2:08* |      |
|--------------------+----------------------+--------+------|
| todo.org           | *File time*          | *1:34* |      |
|                    | Programming          |   0:36 |      |
|                    | \_  support forum    |        | 0:36 |
|                    | Courses              |   0:58 |      |
|                    | \_  school 2016      |        | 0:58 |
|--------------------+----------------------+--------+------|
| todo_ProjectA.org  | *File time*          | *0:34* |      |
|                    | Financial            |   0:21 |      |
|                    | \_  Progress reports |        | 0:21 |
|                    | WP4                  |   0:13 |      |
|                    | \_  User support     |        | 0:13 |
#+END:
```

Changing Q3 to Q2 or Q1 gives the same result. It looks like the calculation of quarters is broken.
I guess this may have to do with my upgrading Org-mode to 8.3 about a month ago.

Did anyone experience this too or is it something with my setup?

[edit] I upgraded to org 20151005 from the package repo and the problem persists.

[edit 2] Using Org 8.2.10 I get the correct result, so this indeed seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a bug. After upgrading to the Org package of 20151116, the calendar works OK again.